# Count the child Node

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have below payload ,where I have to count number of child elements under `<Document>`.
For example:

```
<Document>
  <Class>D</Class>`enter code here`
  <ClassDescription>Drawings</ClassDescription>
  <ClientDocumentNumber>12345</ClientDocumentNumber>
<Document>
```

The count will be 3.

The Payload is as below. Check this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InputVariable>
    <part  name="payload">
        <ProjectMessage>
            <ConversationId>E53252F709653493E0401E0A13916A2E</ConversationId>
            <SourceApplicationId>Convero</SourceApplicationId>
            <Operation>INS DOC</Operation>
            <ModifiedByUserEmail>daviD.Woo@xyz.com</ModifiedByUserEmail>
            <Project>
                <Id>100020</Id>
                <DocumentList>
                    <Document>
                        <Class>D</Class>
                        <ClassDescription>Drawings</ClassDescription>
                        <ClientDocumentNumber>12345</ClientDocumentNumber>
                        <ClientRevisionNumber>2.0</ClientRevisionNumber>
                        <Discipline>141</Discipline>
                        <DisciplineDescription>ACN</DisciplineDescription>
                        <Facility>24</Facility>
                        <Number>100020-24-140-SKT-0002</Number>
                        <OSROriginator>086238</OSROriginator>
                        <Revision>2.0</Revision>
                        <RevisionDate>2013-02-11T00:00:00Z</RevisionDate>
                        <Status>A</Status>
                        <StatusDescription>Active</StatusDescription>
                        <SupplierDocumentNumber>523570.000</SupplierDocumentNumber>
                        <SupplierRevisionNumber>CCC</SupplierRevisionNumber>
                        <Title>Test for FileNet</Title>
                        <Type>NA</Type>
                        <TypeDescription>NA</TypeDescription>
                    </Document>
                </DocumentList>
            </Project>
        </ProjectMessage>
    </part>
</InputVariable>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Document">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(*)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

is a template matching `Document` elements and counting the child elements.

Comment: I wants to count number of child elements under <Document> element.

Comment: @ranjitsingh, the posted code does that, it matches on `Document` elements and then counts the number of child elements. If you want to count matching further up in the document hierarchy then use `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:value-of select="count(//Document/*)"/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: I am using this xslt code for find childe node buts its giving me the xapth xrpession error under Oracle Jdevelpoer.

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="count(/imp1:ProjectMessage/imp1:Project/imp1:DocumentList/imp1:Document[1]/imp1:Document/*)">

Comment: Code which giving me the error

<xsl:for-each select="count(/imp1:ProjectMessage/imp1:Project/imp1:DocumentList/imp1:Document[‌​1]/*)">sorry right code is

Comment: Show us a sample of the XML you have. The sample you have shown so far does not use any namespaces at all so using a prefix like `imp1` does not make sense.